# How to define string as luis entity

Tags: bots, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I'm working with Luis.ai, I can define entity as a word but dont know how to define entity as a string, for example:

- I am working on setting up my computer

I want to receive entity = "setting up my computer"

Currently, Luis return entity = "setting"

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making the Entity "computer" and the Intent "Setting Up"? And, you could add phrase lists such as "computer, laptop, desktop, machine" and "setting up, configuring, installing, building". Based on your example, it seems like this is the direction you are intending to go